# workaround for TimerService with stateful ejb

Tags: jakarta-ee, timer, ejb

I have stateful ejb for tickets order. I want to implement a feature that if user selects tickets but doesn't pay for them, that are hold for him for specific period of time, say 10 min. So I implemented that when user submits selection of tickets, they are deleted from the database of available tickets. Now I need to set a timer that on a timeout will check if the payment was made (it's possible through the database) and if not - will return those tickets to the database.

I would do so in a ejb for tickets order, but it's a stateful one, and EJBTimer service doesn't support stateful beans. How would you suggest to do it?

Is it possible to delegate the mission of handling the timeout to separate stateless bean? In this case it will have only the method creating the timer and method annotated with @Timeout. I don't know how to pass all the details about the selected tickets to the stateless bean, because they can't be kept as bean properties (cause of bean being stateless). I can pass them only to the method creating the timer, but they have to be used in the method called at timeout.

P.S. I'm using glassfish 3.1

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass details to the timeout method by passing information while creating the timer.

Either you can pass serialized object - appropriate data structure to hold ticket information or can alter the existing class to implement `Serializable` interface.

`createTimer(long duration, Serializable info)`

Now, later after the timeout period, you can fetch this `info` object in the timeout method by invoking `getInfo()` on the `Timer` object.

*[There are other methods available with different signature for creating Timer]*